# Retrieving many to many results from gorm with condition

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

for example this is my model

```golang
type User struct {
  gorm.Model
  Languages []Language `gorm:"many2many:user_languages;"`
}

type Language struct {
  gorm.Model
  Name string
}
```

I want to get users that has English language. How can I set the condition? I have tried this and it does not work:

```golang
db.Preload("Languages").Where("Language.Name = ?", conditionVal).Find(&users)
```

Comment: The condition should be passed in `Preload()` along with that model.
`db.Preload("Languages", "Name = ?", whichName).Find(&users)`

Comment: @HaiTH When I do this I get this error `Error 1054: Unknown column 'users.name' in 'where clause'`

Comment: @MoeinHosseini Recheck again you are putting condition inside Preload or not. It's worked for me.

Comment: @HaiTH `db.Preload("Genres", "Slug = ?", genre)` this is my actual code. I have tracks that can have many genres

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Preload users from Language

```
language := Language{}
db.Where("Name = ?", langVal).Preload("Users").Find(&language)
users := language.Users
```

You models need backreference also

```
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    Languages []*Language `gorm:"many2many:user_languages;"`
}

type Language struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name  string
    Users []*User `gorm:"many2many:user_languages;"`
}
```

Offical doc: [Preload with conditions](https://gorm.io/docs/preload.html#Preload-with-conditions)

Comment: This code filters the languages of each user. I want to filter users based on available language